# What is the whole list of assumption that Ho Lee model was under?

Tags: modeling, models

What is the whole list of assumption that Ho Lee model was under?

Please briefly describe how was each assumption match the real world finance/economics applications so that it shows how the model can had real application.

I can find no reference to these question.

Comment: What do you want? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki The question is asking how to derive the model from a list of assumption.